# One of my posts was removed, can I find out why?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I noticed I had a reputation change and found this in the user -> reputation page, under 'Yesterday' (which was the 8th of November for me):

`-20    22:12   removed     Jquery animate opacity - IE8 bug`

However there was no link, and I can't find a record of me asking that question or answering or commenting on it - so I've got no idea what I said or did and why it was removed.

How can I find out the reason for removal, so I can atleast make sure I don't do it again?

Needless to say I can't remember the details of the question, I'd really like to be able to read through it again, mostly to make sure I wasn't being unfair or insulting - without being able to see it I don't know if it was deserved or not, or how to learn from it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [question you answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820662/jquery-animate-opacity-ie8-bug) (10k+ only) was deleted:

> **closed as too localized by casperOne♦ 20 hours ago**
>   This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.

The OP had figured out what the problem was:

> I figured this out. Turns out that my CSS selector was the issue.

which made the question very much too localized.

You yourself didn't do anything wrong; the question in, ahem, question was rubbish. When the question was deleted, your answer (which received 2 upvotes) was deleted with it and you lost the reputation for it. Bad luck!

When a post is deleted, any reputation you earned is removed again, as if you never answered at all. The negative reputation count you see is the proper accounting at work; you are notified on the day that a post is deleted of the loss of previously-earned reputation.

Without a little Google magic (to find the question) and a reputation of 10K or up, there isn't really much you can do to find out why the question was deleted. Unless you come to meta of course. :-)

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. Reassuring to know, however this does raise another point - I had no idea I could receive negative rep for answering a question that is later removed. Thanks for explaining though, it's good to know I didn't do anything wrong :)

Comment: @jammypeach You didn't get negative rep, per se; it just removed the positive rep you got from the answer in the first place, leaving you right where you would be if that question/answer had never existed.

Comment: AHA! OK now I get it! yes of course that makes sense, should have picked that up. head full of the cold today, it's like thinking in wet treacle. thanks :)

Comment: I think that some of the closing decisions are flawed. Taking the points away for a perfectly valid answer is just plain wrong.